# How to get Filterable Attributes from a category in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created category "Bag" in Magento 2. having filter attribute:

1. color
2. Size

I'm trying to get Filterable Attributes from category "Bag".

I have already done this in Magento 1.9:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store);
$layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
$category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($categoryid);  
$layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
$attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();
```

But it does not seem to work for 2.x

Answer (score 22):

I faced the same problem recently.

I documented my investigation [here](http://www.sivaschenko.com/magento2-sales-order-grid-column/).

I was not able to find framework api to provide filterable attributes for specific category, however I will share workarounds.

Basically all filterable attributes in Magento 2 can be retrived from **FilterableAttributeList**:

```
$filterableAttributes = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);
$attributes = $filterableAttributes->getList();
```

Please use DI instead of ObjectManager::getInstance(). I used it just to have more compact example :)

Retrieving filters involved in layered navigation is a bit more tricky.

```
$filterableAttributes = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);

$appState = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
$layerResolver = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
$filterList = ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::class,
    [
        'filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes
    ]
);

$category = 1234;

$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$layer = $layerResolver->get();
$layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
$filters = $filterList->getFilters($layer);
```

However, this is not the final result. To be sure that filters are actual, it is required to check number of items for each filters. (that check is actually performed during core layered navigation [rendering](//github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/LayeredNavigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/view.phtml#L38))

```
$finalFilters = [];
foreach ($filters as $filter) {
    if ($filter->getItemsCount()) {
        $finalFilters[] = $filter;
    }
}
```

Then you can get filter names and values. ie:

```
$name = $filter->getName();
foreach ($filter->getItems() as $item) {
    $value = $item->getValue();
}
```

Finally, I would like to add alternative solution, that is a bit brutal, thought :)

```
$categoryId = 1234;

$resource = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::class);
$connection = $resource->getConnection();

$select = $connection->select()->from(['ea' => $connection->getTableName('eav_attribute')], 'ea.attribute_id')
->join(['eea' => $connection->getTableName('eav_entity_attribute')], 'ea.attribute_id = eea.attribute_id')
->join(['cea' => $connection->getTableName('catalog_eav_attribute')], 'ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id')
->join(['cpe' => $connection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity')], 'eea.attribute_set_id = cpe.attribute_set_id')
->join(['ccp' => $connection->getTableName('catalog_category_product')], 'cpe.entity_id = ccp.product_id')
->where('cea.is_filterable = ?', 1)
->where('ccp.category_id = ?', $categoryId)
->group('ea.attribute_id');

$attributeIds = $connection->fetchCol($select);
```

Then it is possible to use attribute ids to load collection.

```
 /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection */
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$collection->setItemObjectClass('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute')
        ->addStoreLabel($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
$collection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_id', ['in' => $attributeIds]);
```

Comment: @Segey: It's returns only attribute code. I need it's all available labels with value

Comment: For filters - use $filter->getName(), $filter->getItems()->getValue().If you referring to the last solution - use ids to load Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection. I will add a line to answer

Comment: I'm getting duplicate filter name by using : $filter->getName()

Comment: Well, it depends on your data. Anyway that's exactly how Magento renders layered navigation: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/LayeredNavigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/view.phtml

Comment: I think it's working for me. Can you please do one more help for me:
I need $filter code and frontend_input..

Comment: @SergeyIvashchenko can you please help me to get it work for Search Result Page as well. Because Category ID is not found on Search Result Page. Really Appreciate your help.

Comment: For anyone wanting the actual attribute code use $filter->getRequestVar() in above examples

Comment: You will run into problems if you for `$layer->setCurrentCategory($category);` globally which is my case. therefore every category page that I load will change the mysql query to fetch for the one you set. I'm trying to find alternative anyone any ideas ?

Comment: Does anyone know how to get only the attribute items that apply for the selected category? When I do `$filter->getItems()` I get back every single one of them even if there are no products with any of them in that category.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to build module then you can take help from 'FiltersProvider.php' from 'module-catalog-graph-ql\Model\Resolver\Layer'.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList as CategoryFilterableAttributeList;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterListFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

public function __construct(
    Resolver $layerResolver,
    FilterListFactory $filterListFactory,
    CategoryFilterableAttributeList $categoryFilterableAttributeList,
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder
) {
    $this->_navigation = $navigation;
    $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    $this->filterListFactory = $filterListFactory;
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    $this->_categoryFilterableAttributeList = $categoryFilterableAttributeList;
}
public function getCatMenu($catid)
{
    $fill_arr = [];

    $filterList = $this->filterListFactory->create(['filterableAttributes' => $this->_categoryFilterableAttributeList]);

    $layer = clone $this->layerResolver->get();
    $layer->setCurrentCategory($catid);
    $filters =  $filterList->getFilters($layer);

    return $fill_arr;
}
```